# What is a better way to respond to numeric keypresses?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, keyeventargs, keypreview

I want to allow the checking of radio buttons via the keyboard, specifically via the numbers 1, 2, 3. I've got this code that works:

```
// "a WPF form hears what it wants to hear and disregards the rest" - paraphrased from "The Boxer" by Simon & Garfunkel
private void Window_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs keArgs)
{
    var keyPressed = keArgs.Key.ToString();
    if ((keyPressed.Equals("D1")) || (keyPressed.Equals("NumPad1")))
    {
        rdbtnCandidateVal1.IsChecked = true;
    }
    else if ((keyPressed.Equals("D2")) || (keyPressed.Equals("NumPad2")))
    {
        rdbtnCandidateVal2.IsChecked = true;
    }
    else if ((keyPressed.Equals("D3")) || (keyPressed.Equals("NumPad3")))
    {
        rdbtnCandidateVal3.IsChecked = true;
    }
}
```

...but know this is kludgy'verbose. What is a better way to take action for a subset of keys and disregard the rest?

Comment: Those should be else if's seeing how if the first one is true you shouldn't have to bother with any of the other comparisons. I would say you could extract out a method, kind of like `CheckRadioButton(string[] acceptedKeys, RadioButton radioButton)` and do your logic in there. I guess that would make it look less "kludgy'verbose".

Comment: True; I updated the code above and the real code.

Comment: @austinwernli, good suggestion for the If/Else change, but my first coding instructor suggested using case statements when I need more than two If conditions.

Comment: What about a custom RadioButton control class that maybe has a property string[] of acceptedKeys? Last idea i'm throwing out there ha